# "Più/meno prioritario di" è corretto? Ha senso?

Tags: grammar, adjectives, comparison

Voce **prioritario** del [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/prioritario/):

> Che ha la priorità, che deve avere la priorità, cioè la precedenza, in
>   quanto più importante, più valido, più significativo, ecc.

È corretto usare questo aggettivo per un confronto?
Ha senso dire "il problema A è più prioritario del problema B", oppure no in quanto l'aggettivo implica già un confronto?

Comment: Assumendo che **A** e **B** siano entrambe prioritarie *rispetto ad altri fattori*, «**A** è prioritaria rispetto a **B**» è senz'altro preferibile a «**A** è più prioritaria di **B**»: quest'ultima suona come una forzatura che forse si potrebbe ammorbidire mettendo le virgolette («**A** è "più prioritaria" di **B**»). Comunque, googlando "più prioritario rispetto" e "più prioritario di" si ottengono tanti risultati, segno che, giusto o sbagliato che sia, si usa.

Comment: *Prioritario* deriva dal latino *prior*, che è già un comparativo; *più prioritario* è come *più migliore*.

Comment: Per favore non rispondete utilizzando i commenti

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Benché, come osservato dal egreg, ["prioritario"](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/prioritario/) derivi dalla radice latina "prior", che è comparativo di maggioranza, tale derivazione è mediata attraverso il latino medievale [prioritas](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/priorita/). In italiano "prioritario" risulta essere un semplice aggettivo qualificativo: nulla impedisce che gli elementi di X, prioritari rispetto agli elementi di Y, siano tra loro diversamente prioritari. Quindi in linea di principio potrebbero considerarsi accettabili i comparativi "più prioritario" o "maggiormente prioritario".

Tuttavia, assumendo che i fattori **A** e **B** siano entrambi prioritari rispetto ad altri fattori,

> «**A** è prioritario rispetto a **B**»

è senz'altro preferibile ad

> «**A** è più prioritario di **B**»,
>
> «**A** è più prioritario rispetto a **B**»,
>
> «**A** è maggiormente prioritario rispetto a **B**»

Queste ultime suonano come una forzatura che si potrebbe forse ammorbidire mettendo le virgolette («"più prioritario"», «"maggiormente prioritario"»).

Comunque, googlando "maggiormente prioritario", "più prioritario rispetto" e "più prioritario di" si ottengono tanti risultati, segno che, giuste o sbagliate che siano, queste forme si usano.

**EDIT** @Numbers

Se fosse semplice come tu suggerisci, anche la locuzione "massima priorità" sarebbe errata, giusto? E invece, se anche fosse errata in linea di principio, è una locuzione che l'[uso](https://www.google.it/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=b-iQU7HAGaqN8QeIn4GgDw&gws_rd=cr#q=%22massima+priorit%C3%A0%22&tbm=bks), diffuso in ogni possibile contesto **colto**, ha chiaramente reso legittima. Lo stesso vale anche in inglese: nessuno metterebbe in discussione che "[top priority](https://www.google.it/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=b-iQU7HAGaqN8QeIn4GgDw&gws_rd=cr#q=%22top+priority%22&tbm=bks)", "[highest priority](https://www.google.it/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=b-iQU7HAGaqN8QeIn4GgDw&gws_rd=cr#q=%22highest+priority%22&tbm=bks)" o "[greatest priority](https://www.google.it/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=b-iQU7HAGaqN8QeIn4GgDw&gws_rd=cr#q=%22greatest+priority%22&tbm=bks)" siano perfettamente accettabili. Addirittura, per identificare la relazione 'ordine tra diversi elementi, si parla di "[priority queue](https://www.google.it/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=b-iQU7HAGaqN8QeIn4GgDw&gws_rd=cr#q=priority+queue&tbm=bks)".

Comment: Quindi sarebbe legittimo usare anche il superlativo relativo?
"Il più prioritario tra i miei problemi è questo"?
In questo caso, a mio parere, è evidente come ciò possa risultare **errato** rispetto a "Tra i miei problemi, questo è prioritario.", in quanto tale uso dell'aggettivo porta già il significato di "più urgente rispetto agli altri".

Comment: *priorità* ha perso il significato comparativo latino, e non vedo nulla di male a dire che A ha priorità maggiore di B. Con *prioritario* però le cose mi paiono diverse.

Comment: @mau "prioritario" deriva dal latino "prioritas" ed in italiano è un aggettivo qualificativo. Quindi mi pare che nulla, formalmente, ne vieti la formazione del comparativo. Detto questo, sono d'accordo che "più/meno prioritario" non suoni benissimo (mentre invece "diversamente prioritari" - comparativo di disuguaglianza - secondo me suona bene).